# How to restrict file system when logged into terminal services: single login name

Tags: windows, security

**What I need to accomplish:** With one login, when they are in the building I need them to see everything.  When they are using terminal services with same login they should not be able to see the network.  I can lock down the PC running terminal services as that is its only use.

**Details:**

1. Windows/2003 Server with terminal services.
2. One login for a user (e.g., johndoe).
3. When johndoe logs into the network at his desk in the office, he can see the network files according to group policy.
4. When johndoe logs into terminal services from outside the building, we do not want to allow him see the network.  Using 2x to do a published app, but that app has a "feature" that allows user to see network.

Published application on termina services (only) is a document management system that is tied to windows login, so I can't give them two logins.

With one login, when they are in the building I need them to see everything.  When they are using terminal services they should not be able to see the network.  I can lock down the PC running terminal services as that is its only use.

My network engineer says it can't be done.  True?

Comment: This is not programming related.  It should be asked on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done through software and the product has already been implemented.

See the following and read up on Application Network Access Control:

http://www.appsense.com/products/applicationmanager.aspx

This product has many other benefits for Terminal Servers too.

Answer (score 0):

If this gets moved to serverfault, the answer will be it can't be done.

However, a sufficiently powerful programmer could solve this problem.

The solution is a custom application firewall on the terminal server that denies access to the network if it sees the user is from outside the building via finding the remote IP of their particular session.

Congratulations, you have yourself a $40,000 (wild guess) piece of software to develop.